# Sending files with socket : 1 sec sleep or nanosleep needed

Tags: c, file, sockets, networking

i'm writing a client/server application in C and i've noticed a trouble that is confusing me a little bit.

If i send a single file everything works fine,but when i try to send every file in the current working directory client blocks ( on a read system call i think ).
I've tried to write a sleep(1) instruction and it works.

Here is the code of the function that sends all the files.

```
while((p =readdir(d))){

    /* We DO NOT want to transfer these files */
    if(!strcmp(p->d_name,".") || !strcmp(p->d_name,"..") || !strcmp(p->d_name,".DS_Store") || !strcmp(p->d_name,"clientS") || !strcmp(p->d_name,"clientS.c"))
        continue;
    if(stat(p->d_name,&file_stat) < 0){
        perror("Stat error");
    }

    if(S_ISREG(file_stat.st_mode)){

        //printf("sending : %s\n ",p->d_name);
        send_file(p->d_name,Socket_d);
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

I'm testing with 127.0.0.1 IP address (localhost)

send_file function code :

```
 byte_left = file_stat.st_size;
/* while there are bytes to send loop */
while(byte_left > 0){
    memset(sendbuf,0,sizeof(sendbuf));
    /*read data from file*/
    nread = fread(sendbuf,1,sizeof(sendbuf),filepointer);
    sendbuf[nread] = '\0';
    if(write(sock_fd,sendbuf,sizeof(sendbuf)) < 0){
        perror("Writing error");
        return -1;
    }
    byte_left -= nread;
}
close(fd);
```

Comment: the client code might be more useful. And how it interacts with send_file.

Comment: I see three problems with your send_file implementation. `sendbuf[nread] = '\0';` can go beyond the allocated space if nread == sizeof(sendbuff). Instead of `write(sock_fd,sendbuf,sizeof(sendbuf))` you probably ment `write(sock_fd,sendbuf,nread)`, Finally, `write(sock_fd,sendbuf,nread)` does not necessarily write `nread` bytes. It can write less. You shall check its return value.

Comment: Is the client code under your control? Do you check what `read()` returns? Especially comparing to how many bytes you told `read()` to read? If not do so, as `read()`ing from a socket does not necessarily read as much bytes as it was told. Read `read()`'s man-page's *RETURN VALUE* section carefully.